# custom form control custom client side validation in Kentico

Tags: javascript, c#, kentico

We've created a custom `FormEngineUserControl` to capture date input using 3 text inputs for day/month/year.

On the server we override the `bool IsValid()` method which works fine and displays the error message if invalid.

However we want to use client side validation also, we can use a `CustomValidator` control and assign a `ClientValidationFunction` to call a JS method however this is not then combined with the server validation function and we end up with two validation messages, one that removes when client validation passes, and one that only disappears when the form is re-submit, basically rendering the client validation useless.

Is there no way to register a client validation method with a custom form control? that will then be combined with the server method and error label etc. ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work pretty much like any other .net user control. How are you preventing further processing if the validator returns false? You might need to set StopProcessing property to true.

There a few similar topics which might address your porblem:

[stop execution in Custom validator if it false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220312/stop-execution-in-custom-validator-if-it-false)
[Custom validator fires but does not prevent postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8170319/custom-validator-fires-but-does-not-prevent-postback)

Comment: I don't think it works quite like a user control, Kentico is adding it's own server validation, and the client side validation method on the `CustomValidator` doesn't seem to even fire.  We have manual code to fire it upon tabbing but it's all getting a bit messy

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible as I'm not sure how you could combine client vs server side validation. You cannot ever disable server side validation. The client side validation is just there for better UX, its not secured by any means. The general idea this is used is that you disable form submission until all fields are verified on the client side. If the validation is the same on the server, you should not see the same error messages because otherwise it wouldn't go pass the client in the first place.

The way you could do this in Kentico is to use some custom js (or better yet some framework/library to help you with validation such as [validate.js](https://validatejs.org)), give Kentico form some id/class and connect the form validation with your js and have each side (client/server) do its job.